# Safe to Disable getty@.service

Tags: linux, centos7, systemd

Few questions: 
- What does getty@.service do?
- What are the side-effect (or functionality loss) after disabling it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

getty is the process that manages logins on the console and on serial ports, if any. It's generally not safe to disable this, as console access is what we go to when other means of accessing a server fail.

Comment: Odd that redhat article suggests to turn off this service for performance reason.  So it should like as a side effect, I can't even ssh into the server if I have it off (even if sshd is running)?

Comment: No, getty is separate from ssh. And I have no idea what redhat article you mean, as I didn't see one linked anywhere.

Comment: Ok, then what's the "console" you refer to?  Sorry, forgot to include the link: http://people.redhat.com/jmario/docs/201501-perf-brief-low-latency-tuning-rhel7-v2.0.pdf , page 6

Comment: @Hei The console is the physical keyboard, monitor, etc., connected to the system, from which you can use it directly. And, that PDF indicates that `getty@.service` is one of the minimal list of services you should leave enabled.

Comment: In that case, it sounds like getty isn't necessary when the machine is in a restricted data center as usually the server is managed over ssh and the server usually has IPMI (or alike).  No?

Comment: @Hei If you use IPMI to get to the machine, that _is_ the console. You are simply accessing the console over the network. If getty was not running, then you would not be able to use the console.

Comment: Very appreciate for your answer!  Thanks!  Enjoy your weekend :)